# Grub does not load efi partition itself

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grub-efi

I have a laptop Windows 10 installed in it, I am running my machine on Legacy mode. When I have installed Ubuntu so at the time of installation it said I need to create an ESP partition for EFI and after watching a few videos I created EFI partition at `/boot` once I restarted after finishing installation.

Nothing was working neither Ubuntu nor my Windows 10, I am really upset a lot with this, now while booting it says no bootable drive found always.

After looking at few solution I managed how to run Ubuntu, I always open boot menu in my BIOS and select *BOOT from EFI file* then going to location `/boot/efi/ubuntu/grubx64` then only it's running. It's not showing me GRUB.

I have not formatted my Windows yet as it is installed in other drive please tell me how I can get the GRUB showing without doing the manual stuff to running ubuntu directly, and I can add my Windows 10 to boot menu

Comment: Boot into Live Ubuntu and run `sudo parted -l`. Post output into question.

Comment: I tried running boot-repair but still nothing helped. If logs are useful for you
They're here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rxkMrytGSz/

Comment: Can you post this up properly. Copy the output then paste it using the code sample braces in your question

Comment: I pasted it here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2Myky8bSt4/